# Unable to load the spring beans inside the webapplication

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I am having a helper class inside my web application which is responsible to invoke a method on a spring bean.

Below is the class definition:

```
package org.learning.spring.remoting;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class ClientInvoker {
    public static int sum(int a, int b) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:client-beans.xml");
        Calculation calculation = (Calculation)  context.getBean("calculationBean");
        return calculation.add(a, b);
    }
}
```

Inside my jsp below is the code which invokes the function on `ClienInvoker`

```
<%@page import="org.learning.spring.remoting.ClientInvoker"%>  

<%  
  int a=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number"));  
  int b=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number"));  
  out.print("cube of "+ClientInvoker.sum(a, b));  
%>
```

When I run the web application, I am getting the below exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [client-beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [client-beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:555)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Basically, its not loading the `client-beans.xml` file which I have placed under the WEB-INF directory.

Can someone let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: put it inside classes folder and try...

Comment: working fine now. Thanks @SMA but why is so. It should work if I put the file directly inside the WEB-INF directory or inside the lib directory right.

Comment: Not if you include it with "classpath:".

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this... Unless you want memory issues, transactional issue, db starvation (if you have datasource). Never (re)create an `ApplicationContext` because you need a bean. You shouldn't even be accessing beans from your JSP. You should use proper separation.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum Could you please let me know how to access the `ApplicationContext` inside a servlet container. I am new to Spring.